# Force linker to include a section in the binary

Tags: gcc, linker, llvm, compiler-optimization, instrumentation

I'm instrumenting my program with a custom compiler instrumentation pass. The compiler adds a global variable in each module. All the global go to a particular section (`_prof_global`). For each module i can see global with `objdump -h`. But in the final binary the section is removed. Most likely linker is removing it because the globals are unused. Is there a way to force linker to keep that section anyways?

Comment: If I understand you correct, you want `--gc-sections` but you don't want to GC away *that* section?

Comment: yes, like the way we do programmatically with `__attribute__((used))`. The variable may not be used in the program but it still remains in the binary if we annotate with attribute used.

Comment: @A.K. did you by any chance manage to succeed in this endeavour? I can force the compiler to use a symbol from a specific function with `--undefined=_symbol`, but I'd rather not use specific symbols, but rather whole sections. Haven't had any luck with `--unique=SECTION` so far.

Comment: The trick was to put all the globals in a `_DATA, _prof_global` section instead of plain `_prof_global` section: https://reviews.llvm.org/D74362